# How do I pass a const variable to a component as a prop in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am trying to pass the wantedAirline variable into the AirlineSection Component but I keep getting the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'wantedAirline' of undefined` from inside the AirlineSection component.

```
render() {
    const wantedAirline = this.state.wantedAirline.filter(p =>
      p.name.includes(this.state.searchTerm)
    )
    return (
      <div>
        <header>Pokemon Searcher</header>

        <AirlineSection 
        wantedAirline = {wantedAirline}
        airlines = {this.state.airlines}
        handleDelete={this.handleDelete}/>

      </div>
    )
  }
```

The AirlineSection Component looks like this:

```
function AirlineSection(props){
    console.log(props, 'airline section props');
    return(
        <div>
            <h2>Airlines</h2>
            {props.airlines.map(airline => <AirlineCard key={airline.id}  wantedAirline={this.wantedAirline} airline={airline} handleDelete={props.handleDelete}/>)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `wantedAirline={this.wantedAirline}` with `wantedAirline={props.wantedAirline}` as looks like `AirlineSection` is your functional component.

you are passing `wantedAirline` as props so you also have to access it using props.